# How to handle read and write simultaneously in case of ttyUSB in linux C

Tags: linux, c, serial-port

I want to write application to interface with micro-controller with Linux PC through serial communication. I am able to write the read and write using basic C code using open, read and write function call. But I am not able to understand how to write and read simultaneously.

If do any sample code or logic then please update me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at `select()`?

You can open a file descriptor for the tty device, then start the `select()` call asking for read, write, and exception results, and the `select()` will return to your calling code when the fd has data to read or is ready to be written to, or a timeout has occurred.

[man select](https://linux.die.net/man/3/select)

Comment: the glibc manuals also have example code for `select()`, among other stuff, see e.g.  https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html#Waiting-for-I_002fO